# Change position of button in tkinter window

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I have a check box window and on it there is also a done button (submit). The button is currently at the top of the window, how would I have it at the bottom.
I have tried things like `done_btn.grid(row = 10)` but it hasn't seemed to work.

My code:

```
from tkinter import *

check = Tk()
check.title("Interests")
CheckVar1 = IntVar()
CheckVar2 = IntVar()
CheckVar3 = IntVar()
CheckVar4 = IntVar()
CheckVar5 = IntVar()
CheckVar6 = IntVar()

C1 = Checkbutton(check, text = "Horror", variable = CheckVar1, 
                 onvalue = 1, offvalue = 0, height=1, 
                 width = 20)
C2 = Checkbutton(check, text = "Action", variable = CheckVar2, 
                 onvalue = 1, offvalue = 0, height=1, 
                 width = 20)
C3 = Checkbutton(check, text = "Documentary", variable = CheckVar3, 
                 onvalue = 1, offvalue = 0, height=1, 
                 width = 20)
C4 = Checkbutton(check, text = "Science fiction", variable = CheckVar4, 
                 onvalue = 1, offvalue = 0, height=1, 
                 width = 20)
C5 = Checkbutton(check, text = "Comedy", variable = CheckVar5, 
                 onvalue = 1, offvalue = 0, height=1, 
                 width = 20)
C6 = Checkbutton(check, text = "Drama", variable = CheckVar6, 
                 onvalue = 1, offvalue = 0, height=1, 
                 width = 20)

done_btn = Button(check, text = "Done", command = lambda: check.destroy()) 
done_btn.pack()

C1.pack()
C2.pack()
C3.pack()
C4.pack()
C5.pack()
C6.pack()
check.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 3):

move `done_btn.pack()` past `c6.pack()`

```
C1.pack()
C2.pack()
C3.pack()
C4.pack()
C5.pack()
C6.pack()
done_btn.pack()
```

That being said let me explain why.

When you use `pack()` without defining what `side` to place the widget on tkinter's geometry manager will set the default `.pack(side = "top")`.

As Bryan pointed out in the comments `pack()` can be very useful when used correctly.

I have work more with `grid()` and for this reason I prefer to use `grid()` because I can define a layout quickly and accurately with it.

Instead of using `pack()` consider changing everything to `grid()` so you can more easily define where things go.

Check out the below example using `grid()`

you will see no matter what order we set the grid as long as we use the desired rows and columns the widgets will be placed where we want them:

```
from tkinter import *

check = Tk()
check.title("Interests")
CheckVar1 = IntVar()
CheckVar2 = IntVar()
CheckVar3 = IntVar()
CheckVar4 = IntVar()
CheckVar5 = IntVar()
CheckVar6 = IntVar()

C1 = Checkbutton(check, text = "Horror", variable = CheckVar1, \
                 onvalue = 1, offvalue = 0, height=1, \
                 width = 20)
C2 = Checkbutton(check, text = "Action", variable = CheckVar2, \
                 onvalue = 1, offvalue = 0, height=1, \
                 width = 20)
C3 = Checkbutton(check, text = "Documentary", variable = CheckVar3, \
                 onvalue = 1, offvalue = 0, height=1, \
                 width = 20)
C4 = Checkbutton(check, text = "Science fiction", variable = CheckVar4, \
                 onvalue = 1, offvalue = 0, height=1, \
                 width = 20)
C5 = Checkbutton(check, text = "Comedy", variable = CheckVar5, \
                 onvalue = 1, offvalue = 0, height=1, \
                 width = 20)
C6 = Checkbutton(check, text = "Drama", variable = CheckVar6, \
                 onvalue = 1, offvalue = 0, height=1, \
                 width = 20)

done_btn = Button(check, text = "Done", command = lambda: check.destroy()) 
done_btn.grid(row = 6, column = 0)

C1.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
C2.grid(row = 1, column = 0)
C3.grid(row = 2, column = 0)
C4.grid(row = 3, column = 0)
C5.grid(row = 4, column = 0)
C6.grid(row = 5, column = 0)

check.mainloop()
```

Update:

Just a quick update to an old answer.
To be more DRY and dynamic we can use some list and a "for loop" to reduce the code needed to perform the same task.

Example:

```
import tkinter as tk

check = tk.Tk()
check.title("Interests")
var_list = []
check_list = []
text_list = ['Horror', 'Action', 'Documentary', 'Science fiction', 'Comedy', 'Drama']

for ndex, v in enumerate(text_list):
    var_list.append(tk.IntVar())
    check_list.append(tk.Checkbutton(check, text=v, variable=var_list[-1], onvalue=1, offvalue=0, height=1, width=20))
    check_list[-1].grid(row=ndex, column=0)

tk.Button(check, text='Done', command=check.destroy).grid(row=len(text_list)+1, column=0)
check.mainloop()
```

This is a 26 line difference when we follow the PEP-8 standards more closely and write in a more DRY fashion.

Results:

[image]

Comment: Your description isn't quite right. It won't necessarily place the widget "below the last widget placed". The default option for the `side` attribute is "top", meaning it is placed at the top of the remaining empty space. If you never use the `side` option then it will appear under the last widget. However, if the last widget specified the `side` option with some value other than `top`, then your description is false. Better to say that `pack` "defaults to the top of the empty space" rather than "below the last item placed. "

Comment: As a rule of thumb, you should always include the `side` attribute with `pack` so that the result is less ambiguous.

Comment: @BryanOakley Thanks for the correction Bryan I will edit my answer.

Comment: `pack` is quite powerful when you understand how it works, and for a simple vertical or horizontal layout it's arguably superior to `grid`.

Comment: @BryanOakley: I will have to play around a bit with `pack()` most of my apps so fare use the the very basic uses of pack and are very heavy on `grid()`.

Comment: @BryanOakley I have updated my answer. Its 2 bad the OP's account is gone. They missed out on some good info.